# Parallel.For - almost got this working

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a collection of about 3500 product Serial Numbers that my software uses to create reports with about 10 times a week.

My code retrieves from a very flat database (think Excel spreadsheet) where it pulls 0 to 25+ records from a single table for each Serial Number. I pass this data to a `static` method that generates an instance of my `CustomClass`, and stores that in a collection to be passed back at the end of the routine.

This report typically takes about 20 minutes to run. A lot of that is limited by the data requests being sent to the old *SQL 2000 Server*, but the static class was written to alleviate as much string manipulations and data conversions as possible.

I want to write a [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx) to try and make this run even faster, but I can't figure out how to complete my routine.

Here is the simplified version of the routine I have now:

```
private CustomClass[] Test1(string[] serialNumbers) {
  List<CustomClass> list = new List<CustomClass>();
  for (int i = 0; i < serialNumber.Length; i++) {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", m_open_conn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@sn", SqlDbType.Char, 20).Value = serialNumber[i];
      table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
    list.Add(CustomClass.CreateSummary(table));
  }
  return list.ToArray();
}
```

The task is to write the code above in a Parallel.For loop. All of the examples I have come across so far are overly simplistic, and do not give me any insight on how to convert my code.

Here is what I have so far, but the second `0` value (the one in my Action/Func statement) says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'jp2code.CustomClass'` ...and I don't really understand enough to know what exactly I need to do to make this work.

```
private CustomClass[] Test1(string[] serialNumbers) {
  List<CustomClass> list = new List<CustomClass>();
  Parallel.For<CustomClass>(0, serialNumbers.Length, () => 0, (i, loop, list) => {
      DataTable table = new DataTable();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", m_open_conn)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@sn", SqlDbType.Char, 20).Value = serialNumber[i];
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
      }
    }, (x) => list.Add(CustomClass.CreateSummary(table))
  );
  return list.ToArray();
}
```

Obviously, I am supposed to be initializing the array with something (not a `0`), but I don't know what exactly to do here.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this blog](http://www.lovethedot.net/2009/02/parallelfor-deeper-dive-parallel.html) a good resource for `Parallel.For`

To simply replace the `for` loop you should be able to do this:

```
private CustomClass[] Test1(string[] serialNumbers) {
  List<CustomClass> list = new List<CustomClass>();
  Parallel.For(0, serialNumber.Length, (i) => {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", m_open_conn)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@sn", SqlDbType.Char, 20).Value = serialNumber[i];
      table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
    list.Add(CustomClass.CreateSummary(table));
  });
  return list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Ironically, I did download that today, but I have not worked through any examples yet.

Comment: Wow. This is cool. My CPU is pegged out. Do you think I could pop any of those transistors inside? :)

Comment: The parallel extensions are cool.  I just used this same technique to turn a 1.5 hour insert into a 4 minute job!

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a fixed set of serial numbers, you really don't need `Parallel.For`.

You can use PLINQ.

```
return serialNumbers.AsParallel().Select(number => { ...get table... }).ToArray();
```

I wouldn't really recommend the `ToArray()` approach though.

Comment: I have not broken into `PLINQ` yet. Is one better than another or is it just another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @jp2code It's a more functional way of going about things, rather then transforming your imperative code into parallel. There are subtle problems which you may face when you have side-effects - for example, `list.Add(...)` is not thread-safe.